The Wacky World of ANSI Escape Sequences?
I just finished creating my first npm package (for learning, not competition) and published it.  Now I want to ask some questions, for example:
Is my method of writing code good (for later maintenance and error handling)?
Is there something better I can do to improve my package (and to improve my upcoming packages as well)?
I would be happy if someone with experience in this matter could leave me an explanatory comment.
Code:
index.js
/**
 * @file                                index
 * @description                         Exports the module
 *
 * @version                             0.0.1
 *
 * @note                                Follows the `MECS` code style
*/


/* ---------------------------------- PACK ---------------------------------- */

    const get                           = require('./src/modules/get');
    const set                           = require('./src/modules/set');
    const prop                          = require('./src/modules/prop');

/* ---------------------------------- ---- ---------------------------------- */


/* ---------------------------------- CORE ---------------------------------- */

    const ansi                          =
    {
        get,
        set,
        prop,
    };

    module.exports                      = ansi;

/* ---------------------------------- ---- ---------------------------------- */

get.js
/**
 * @file                                get
 * @description                         Get anything about ANSI
 *
 * @version                             0.0.1
 *
 * @note                                Follows the `MECS` code style
*/


/* ---------------------------------- PACK ---------------------------------- */

    const M_codes                       = require('../json/ansi-escape-list.json');

/* ---------------------------------- ---- ---------------------------------- */


/* ---------------------------------- CORE ---------------------------------- */

    /**
     * Gets anything about ANSI !
    */
    const get                           =
    {
        /**
         * Returns the object containing the ANSI escape codes.
        */
        codeOf                          : M_codes,

        /**
         * Retrieves the ANSI escape code for the specified attribute.
         *
         * @param {string} ref - The name of the attribute.
         * @throws {Error} If the input is not a string.
         * @return {string|undefined} The ANSI escape code for the specified attribute, or undefined if the attribute is not found.
        */
        attr
        : (ref) =>
        {
            // accept : string only
            if (!ref || typeof ref !== 'string')
            throw new Error('ref must be a not empty string');

            // output : string || undefined
            return get.codeOf.attr[ref];
        },

        /**
         * Retrieves the ANSI escape code for the specified color.
         *
         * @param {string|Array<number>} ref - The color name or RGB values.
         * @param {string} [_for='fg'] - The type of color ('fg' for foreground, 'bg' for background).
         * @throws {Error} If the input is not a valid color name or RGB values.
         * @return {string} The ANSI escape code for the specified color.
        */
        fg
        : (ref, _for = 'fg') =>
        {
            if(!ref)
            throw new Error('ref must be a not empty string/array');

            if(!_for)
            throw new Error('_for must be fg|bg');

            if (typeof ref === 'string')
            {
                // Check if the input is a predefined color name
                if (get.codeOf.colors[_for].hasOwnProperty(ref))
                {
                  return get.codeOf.colors[_for][ref];
                }

                // Check if the hex color code has valid length
                if (ref.length === 7 || ref.length === 4)
                {
                    let hex = ref.replace('#', '');

                    // Expand shorthand hex color codes
                    if (ref.length === 4)
                    {
                        hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
                    }

                    const bigint = parseInt(hex, 16);
                    const r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
                    const g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
                    const b = bigint & 255;
                    return _for == 'fg' ? `\u001b[38;2;${r};${g};${b}m` : `\u001b[48;2;${r};${g};${b}m`;
                }

                else
                {
                    throw new Error('Invalid hex color code');
                }
            }

            else if (Array.isArray(ref) && ref.length === 3)
            {
                // Check if the input is an array representing RGB values
                const [r, g, b] = ref;
                if (typeof r === 'number' && typeof g === 'number' && typeof b === 'number')
                {
                  return _for == 'fg' ? `\u001b[38;2;${r};${g};${b}m` : `\u001b[48;2;${r};${g};${b}m`;
                }

                else
                {
                  throw new Error('RGB values must be numbers');
                }
            }

            else
            {
                throw new Error('ref must be a not empty string or array');
            }
        },

        /**
         * Retrieves the ANSI escape code for the specified background color.
         *
         * @param {string|Array<number>} ref - The color name or RGB values.
         * @throws {Error} If the input is not a valid color name or RGB values.
         * @return {string} The ANSI escape code for the specified color.
        */
        bg
        : (ref) =>
        {
            return get.fg(ref, 'bg');
        }
    };

    module.exports                      = get;

/* ---------------------------------- ---- ---------------------------------- */

set.js
/**
 * @file                                set
 * @description                         Set text to anything with ANSI
 *
 * @version                             0.0.1
 *
 * @note                                Follows the `MECS` code style
*/


/* ---------------------------------- PACK ---------------------------------- */

    const M_codes                       = require('../json/ansi-escape-list.json');
    const get                           = require('./get');

/* ---------------------------------- ---- ---------------------------------- */


/* ---------------------------------- CORE ---------------------------------- */

    /**
     * Sets text to anything with ANSI !
    */
    const set                           =
    {
        /**
         * accept : str = string only, ref = string|array
         *
         * @param {string} str - description of parameter
         * @param {string|array} ref - description of parameter
         * @return {string} color + str + color reset
        */
        fg
        : (str, ref) =>
        {
            // accept : str = string only, ref = string|array
            if (!str || typeof str !== 'string')
            throw new Error('str must be a not empty string');

            if (!ref || (typeof ref !== 'string' ) && !Array.isArray(ref))
            throw new Error('ref must be a not empty string/array');

            // output : color + str + color reset
            return get.fg(ref) + str + get.codeOf.attr.reset;
        },

        /**
         * Sets the background color of a string and returns the modified string.
         *
         * @param {string} str - The string to modify.
         * @param {string|array} ref - The reference to the background color.
         * @return {string} The modified string with the background color applied.
        */
        bg
        : (str, ref) =>
        {
            // accept : str = string only, ref = string|array
            if (!str || typeof str !== 'string')
            throw new Error('str must be a not empty string');

            if (!ref || (typeof ref !== 'string' ) && !Array.isArray(ref))
            throw new Error('ref must be a not empty string/array');

            // output : bg color + str + bg color reset
            return get.bg(ref) + str + get.codeOf.attr.reset;
        },

        /**
         * Applies the specified attribute to a string and returns the modified string.
         *
         * @param {string} str - The string to modify.
         * @param {string|array} ref - The reference to the attribute.
         * @throws {Error} If str is not a non-empty string or ref is not a non-empty string or array.
         * @return {string} The modified string with the attribute applied.
        */
        attr
        : (str, ref) =>
        {
            // accept : str = string only, ref = string|array
            if (!str || typeof str !== 'string')
            throw new Error('str must be a not empty string');

            if (!ref || (typeof ref !== 'string' ) && !Array.isArray(ref))
            throw new Error('ref must be a not empty string/array');

            // output : attr + str + attr reset
            return get.attr(ref) + str + get.codeOf.attr.reset;
        },

        /**
         * Applies styles to a given string.
         *
         * @param {string} str - The string to apply styles to.
         * @param {object} styles - The styles to apply.
         * @param {string} styles.attr - The attribute style to apply.
         * @param {string} styles.bg - The background color style to apply.
         * @param {string} styles.fg - The foreground color style to apply.
         * @throws {Error} If str is not a non-empty string or styles is not an object.
         * @throws {Error} If styles.attr is not a string or styles.bg is not a string or styles.fg is not a string.
         * @return {string} The string with styles applied.
        */
        style
        : (str, styles) =>
        {
            if(!str || typeof str !== "string")
            throw new Error('str must be a not empty string');

            if(!styles || typeof styles !== "object")
            throw new Error('styles must be an object');

            // res
            let res = '';
            {
                // attr
                if(styles.attr)
                res += get.attr(styles.attr);

                // bg
                if(styles.bg)
                res += get.bg(styles.bg);

                // fg
                if(styles.fg || styles.fg)
                res += get.fg(styles.fg);

                // str
                res += str;

                // reset
                res += get.codeOf.attr.reset;
            }

            // output : res
            return res;
        },
    };

    module.exports                      = set;

/* ---------------------------------- ---- ---------------------------------- */

prop.js
/**
 * @file                                prop
 * @description                         properties
 *
 * @version                             0.0.1
 *
 * @note                                Follows the `MECS` code style
*/


/* ---------------------------------- PACK ---------------------------------- */

    const M_codes                       = require('../json/ansi-escape-list.json');
    const get                           = require('./get');
    const set                           = require('./set');

    const segmenter                     = new Intl.Segmenter();

/* ---------------------------------- ---- ---------------------------------- */


/* ---------------------------------- CORE ---------------------------------- */

    /**
     * Properties
    */
    const prop                          =
    {
        /**
         * Function to align the str in the line with a lot of options
         *
         * @param {string} str - The string to align.
         * @param {object} options - Options for alignment.
         * @param {number} options.length - The length of the line.
         * @param {string} options.fill - The character to fill the line with.
         * @param {string} options.align - The character to align with.
         * @param {number} options.padding - The space between the str and the line.
         * @param {number} options.steps - The space between the beginning and end of the line and the terminal itself (right-left).
         * @param {object} options.style - The style to apply.
         * @param {fg} options.style.fg - The foreground color to apply.
         * @param {bg} options.style.bg - The background color to apply.
         * @param {attr} options.style.attr - The attribute to apply.
         * @param {cfg} options.style.fg - The foreground color (for fill characters) to apply.
         * @throws {Error} If str is not a non-empty string or options is not an object.
         * @return {string} The aligned string.
        */
        align
        : (str, options) =>
        {
            const applyStyle = (_str, cond = false, mode = 'fg', value = null) =>
            {
                if(!cond || options.disableStyle)
                return _str;

                if(mode == 'attr')
                _str = set.attr(_str, value);

                if(mode == 'bg')
                _str = set.bg(_str, value);

                if(mode == 'fg')
                _str = set.fg(_str, value);

                return _str
            }

            // accept : str = string only, options = object
            if (!str || typeof str !== 'string')
            throw new Error('str must be a not empty string');

            if (!options || (typeof options !== 'object' ))
            throw new Error('options must be a not empty object');

            // defaults
            {
                if(!options.length)
                options.length = 80

                if(!options.fill)
                options.fill = ' '

                if(!options.align)
                options.align = 'left'

                if(!options.padding)
                options.padding = 0

                if(!options.steps)
                options.steps = 0

                if(options.style === false || options.style === null)
                {
                    options.disableStyle = true
                }
                else
                {
                    options.disableStyle = false
                }

                if(!options.style)
                options.style =
                {
                    fg: options.disableStyle ? '' : 'white',
                    bg: options.disableStyle ? '' : 'black',
                    attr: options.disableStyle ? '' : 'normal',
                    cfg: options.disableStyle ? '' : 'gray'
                }
            }

            // process
            {
                let alignedStr = '';

                if(str.length >= options.length)
                return str

                if(options.padding)
                {
                    const padd = ' '.repeat(Math.floor((options.padding) / 2));
                    str = padd + str + padd;
                }

                if(options.align == 'left')
                {
                    alignedStr
                    = applyStyle(str, options.style.fg, 'fg', options.style.fg)
                    + applyStyle(options.fill.repeat(options.length - str.length), options.style.cfg, 'fg', options.style.cfg);
                }

                else if(options.align == 'right')
                {
                    alignedStr
                    = applyStyle(options.fill.repeat(options.length - str.length), options.style.cfg, 'fg', options.style.cfg)
                    + applyStyle (str, options.style.fg, 'fg', options.style.fg);
                }

                else
                {
                    const len
                    = Math.floor((options.length - str.length) / 2);
                    alignedStr
                    = applyStyle(options.fill.repeat(len), options.style.cfg, 'fg', options.style.cfg)
                    + applyStyle (str, options.style.fg, 'fg', options.style.fg)
                    + applyStyle(options.fill.repeat(len), options.style.cfg, 'fg', options.style.cfg);
                }

                if(options.steps)
                {
                    options.steps = Math.floor(options.steps / 2);
                    alignedStr
                    = ' '.repeat(options.steps)
                    + alignedStr
                    + ' '.repeat(options.steps);
                }
                return alignedStr;
            }
        },

        /**
         * Generates a regular expression for matching ANSI escape codes.
         * @param onlyFirst Whether to match only the first occurrence.
         * @returns {RegExp} A regular expression object.
        */
        getRegex
        : (onlyFirst) =>
        {
            const reg =
            [
                '[\\u001B\\u009B][[\\]()#;?]*(?:(?:(?:(?:;[-a-zA-Z\\d\\/#&.:=?%@~_]+)*|[a-zA-Z\\d]+(?:;[-a-zA-Z\\d\\/#&.:=?%@~_]*)*)?\\u0007)',
                '(?:(?:\\d{1,4}(?:;\\d{0,4})*)?[\\dA-PR-TZcf-nq-uy=><~]))'
            ]
            .join('|');

            return new RegExp(reg, onlyFirst ? undefined : 'g');
        },

        /**
         * Strips ANSI escape codes from a given string.
         *
         * @param {string} string - The input string to strip ANSI escape codes from.
         * @return {string} The input string with ANSI escape codes removed.
         * @throws {TypeError} If the input is not a string.
        */
        strip
        : (string) =>
        {
            const reg = prop.getRegex();

            if (typeof string !== 'string')
            throw new TypeError(`Expected a \`string\`, got \`${typeof string}\``);

            // Even though the regex is global, we don't need to reset the `.lastIndex`
            // because unlike `.exec()` and `.test()`, `.replace()` does it automatically
            // and doing it manually has a performance penalty.
            return string.replace(reg, '');
        },

        /**
         * Calculates the length of a given string, optionally excluding ANSI escape codes.
         *
         * @param {string} string - The input string to calculate the length of.
         * @param {boolean} countAnsiEscapeCodes - Whether to include ANSI escape codes in the length calculation.
         * @return {number} The length of the input string, excluding ANSI escape codes if `countAnsiEscapeCodes` is false.
        */
        length
        : (string, countAnsiEscapeCodes = false) =>
        {
            if (string === '')
            return 0;

            if (!countAnsiEscapeCodes)
            string = prop.strip(string);

            if (string === '')
            return 0;

            let length = 0;

            for (const _ of segmenter.segment(string))
            // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
            length++;

            return length;
        },

    };

    module.exports                      = prop;

/* ---------------------------------- ---- ---------------------------------- */

For more information and examples see the repo on GitHub and the package on npm
Also, for more information, you can read this post: The Wacky World of ANSI Escape Sequences: A Comedic Guide
